# Python application and docker/AWS design question

Tags: python, docker, import

I have a python application that reads/writes to the MySQL database. Previously, I had a single python file and it contained db connection details. However, I'm attempting to abstract it and import into multiple modules. For example, my directory structure is as follows:

```
basedir
    utils
        dbutils.py
    module1
        __init__.py
        src
            code.py
            __init__.py
        requirements.txt
        Dockerfile
    module2
        __init__.py
        src
            code.py
            __init__.py
        requirements.txt
        Dockerfile
```

For importing code from dbutils.py into code.py in module1 and module2 such that it works both locally and also when docker images are built. What would be the correct way? Do I need to package my dbutils.py file and place an import in the requirements.txt? Or is there a way to be included in the image from a simple import statement in the code.py files?

Comment: I would put everything in the same package, then you can import with no extrawork. In the same package you can from mypackage.utils import dbutils, or even from ..utils import dbutils, just make basedir your package, and choose a wise name :)

Comment: Now if you really want to separate utils, make it a package with a setup.py and install usign pip install git+https://yourepo/utils/..., you can put this each requirements, but IMHO this would fragment the code I would go with a single package and mutliple entry points